# Suppose that $A, B$, and $C$ are distinct points in $C$. Suppose that $l$ is the line which bisects $∠BAC$ and $M$ is the line which bisects $∠ACB$

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

Suppose that $A, B$, and $C$ are distinct points in $C$. Suppose that $l$ is the line which bisects $∠BAC$ and $M$ is the line which bisects $∠ACB$. Now let $Z$ be the point $l \cap m$. Let $n$ be the line through $B$ and $Z$. Show that $N$ bisects $∠CBA$. This shows that the angle bisectors of a triangle are concurrent.

[image: Figure One]

$\textbf{Attempt:}$

Construct perpendicular lines from the point $Z$ to the lines $AB,BC$ and $AC$ and label the new point $E,F$ and $G$ respectively.

[image: Figure 2]

Now, angle $GZC$ is congruent to angle $FZC$ by the angle side angle identity. This implies that $ZG=ZF\quad (\star)$.

Also, angle $EZA$ is congruent to angle FZA by the angle side angle identity which implies $ZE=ZF\quad(\star\star).$

Putting $(\star)$ together with $(\star\star)$ shows that $ZG=ZE=ZF.$

Now construct a line from $B$ to $Z$ and label this new line $n$

[image: Figure 3]

By our construction angles $BGZ$ and $BEZ$ are both right angles. Moreover, we may conclude they are congruent angles as the hypotenuse and adjacent sides are equal. Thus, $BGZ=BEZ$ which shows that $n$ is the angle bisector.

I am not entirely sure I have answered this question properly, however, I do not feel there are any flaws in my logic. Would someone please look over and make sure I am on the correct path.

Also, we have not discussed the angle side angle (ASA) identity in class. I did however pick this up from the text we are reading from. wold it be fair game to use this identity or is there another way to go about this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just to see that this generalized quite a bit, you should check out Ceva's theorem.

Comment: Why do you assume B,z, and G are colinear?

Comment: You refer to the angle BGZ when you meant BFZ.  They are right angles by construction.  "Moreover we may assume the are congruent because..."  they are congruent because they are right angles; nothing more need be said.  Also you created line n.  Don't. you have no reason to assume B,z, G are colinear.  And you have no *need* to.  Just connect B to z and do NOT assume you can extend it to G.

Comment: Three errors but otherwise good.  1)GZC and FZC are not congruent by a.s.a.  You don't have adjacent angle side and angle.  They are congruent because the opposite angles of a right triangle are complimentary and complementary angles of congruent angles are congruent.  *Now* you have a.s.a and the *triangles* are congruent.  A.S.A proves triangles  are congruent, not angles or sides.  Once you have congruent triangles corresponding angles and sides are congruent.  So that is how ZG = ZF.

Comment: 2) when you construct line n from B to z, do NOT extend it to G.  You have no reason or need to believe G is on n.  In fact, if this is not an isoceles triangle G is NOT on n.

Comment: 3)"By our construction angles BGZ and BEZ are both right angles."  True.  "Moreover we may conclude they are congruent angles as..."  We may conclude the are congruent because they are right angles.  Period. "Thus BGZ = BEZ which shows n is the angle bisector." Not until you show the triangles are congruent.  You know the triangles are right triangles with shared hypotenuse, and congruent leg and thus ar congruent triangle.  By coresponding parts EBZ=FBZ and n is angle bisector.

Comment: You have a weird habit of justifying *parts* are congruent by triangle cronguency theorems rather than claiming the *triangles* are congruent by the theorems *after* proving the parts are congruent by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your writing an angle can be confused. When you refer to an angle of $\measuredangle PQR$ I understand that you are referring to  angle determined by the intersection of $PR$ and $QR$ segments.

Your attempt begins properly:

> Construct perpendicular lines from the point $z$ to the lines $AB$, $BC$,  and $AC$ and label the new point $E$, $F$, and $G$ respectively.
>
> Now, angle $\measuredangle GZC$ is congruent to angle $\measuredangle FZC$ by the angle side snuggle identity. This implies that $ZG=ZF$ $(⋆)$.

Actually $\measuredangle GZC$ is congruent to angle $\measuredangle FZC$ by **Angle Angle Side postulate**, also,  $ZG=ZF$  is due to **Angle Side Angle postulate**.

> Also, angle $\measuredangle EZA$ is congruent to angle $\measuredangle FZA$ by the angle side angle identity which implies $ZE=ZF$ (⋆⋆).

In the same way, $\measuredangle EZA$ is congruent to angle $\measuredangle FZA$ by **Angle Angle Side postulate**, also,  $ZE=ZF$ is due to **Angle Side Angle postulate**.

> Putting (⋆) together with (⋆⋆) shows that $ZG=ZE=ZF$.

The latter is fine.

> By our construction angles $\measuredangle BGZ$ and $\measuredangle BEZ$ are both right angles. Moreover, we may conclude they are congruent angles as the hypotenuse and adjacent sides are equal. Thus, $\measuredangle BGZ=\measuredangle BEZ$ which shows that $n$ is the angle bisector.

The conclusion you get is due to you have two right triangles with the same hypotenuse and two equal sides, then by the Pythagoras Theorem  the other pair of sides are also  equals, i.e, $EB=BF$. Therefore,  $\measuredangle BGZ=\measuredangle BEZ$ by **Side Side Side postulate**.

Overall your argument is correct.

Comment: @Blue You are right, it is already corrected.

Comment: There is no such thing as angle angle side nor angle side side.  Those simply don't work.

Comment: The angles are congruent because they are complimentary to congruent angles.

Comment: We don't give a crap the the other pair of sides are congruent.  We conclude the *triangles* are congruent because the are right triangles with equal (shared avtually) hypotenuse and congruent side.  By *corresponding parts* we conclude the angles are congruent.  (We can also conclude the remaining pair are and the remaining angles are but we don't give a damn about those.)  Side side side concludes *triangles* are congruent.  Not parts.  (And we didn't have side side side anyway.)